# How can you Merge sort a .Net framework LinkedList (of T)

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, linked-list

There's a few questions discussing Merge sorting a LinkedList, but how can I do it with the C# LinkedList?

Since the LinkedListNode Next and Previous properties are read-only most of the in-place algorithms I've come across are not possible.

I've resorted to removing all the nodes, sorting them with a .OrderBy(node => node.Value) and then re-inserting them into the Linked list, but it's fairly crude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can re-order nodes by calling `Remove`, then `AddAfter`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind merging to a new sequence, the following sample app demonstrates an algorithm to merge two sorted sequences:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Merge
{
    class Program
    {
        static IEnumerable<T> Merge<T>(IEnumerable<T> left, IEnumerable<T> right)
            where T: IComparable<T>
        {
            IEnumerator<T> l = left.GetEnumerator();
            IEnumerator<T> r = right.GetEnumerator();

            bool l_has_data = l.MoveNext();
            bool r_has_data = r.MoveNext();

            while (l_has_data || r_has_data)
            {
                if (!l_has_data && r_has_data)
                {
                    yield return r.Current;
                    r_has_data = r.MoveNext();
                    continue;
                }
                if (!r_has_data && l_has_data)
                {
                    yield return l.Current;
                    l_has_data = l.MoveNext();
                    continue;
                }

                int comp = l.Current.CompareTo(r.Current);
                if (comp < 0)
                {
                    yield return l.Current;
                    l_has_data = l.MoveNext();
                }
                else if (comp > 0)
                {
                    yield return r.Current;
                    r_has_data = r.MoveNext();
                }
                else
                {
                    yield return l.Current;
                    yield return r.Current;
                    l_has_data = l.MoveNext();
                    r_has_data = r.MoveNext();
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var left = new[] { 1, 4, 7, 9, 10 };
            var right = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 6, 8, 9, 11 };

            foreach (var i in Merge(left, right))
                Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
    }
}
```

This could be cleaned up a bit with refactoring & what-not, but it's purely meant to demonstrate the merge. As written, it also works with any enumerable sequences, not just linked lists.

Note the sample, as shown produces this output:

```
1
1
2
3
4
6
7
8
9
9
10
11
```

Comment: Perhaps my wording was not clear, but I want to sort the linked list, not merge two already sorted lists.